# How do I add a feature to openlayers map hosted on geoserver?

Tags: openlayers, postgis, openlayers-3, geoserver

I have a map of one layer displaying countries. It is hosted on geoserver and the layer is stored in my postgis database. I need to be able to allow an user to add other countries on the map for example (just one point is enough). How can I achieve this? I saw some people using openlayers library and somehow communicating with the localhost map.. but I am not able to find any tutorials. I don't think that what I'm trying to do is hard.. but I don't know how to begin.. Any directions ?

Comment: A tutorial of sorts here 
http://www.quadratic.be/en/openlayers-3-update-vector-layers-with-wfs-t-transactional-protocol/
an old question using similar code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440460/openlayers-3-wfs-t-post-feature-to-postgis-via-geoserver/32094049
and possible problems with OL's non-standard EPSG:4326
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648061/error-when-posting-features-to-postgis-by-openlayers-and-geoserver

Comment: What do you mean by add other countries with one point?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Openlayers. I need guidance on below.

I am able to create map using openlayers and able to create polygon interactions on the map and able to extract as GeoJson object with coordinates.

Now i need to send this GeoJson request to my GeoServer to get the intersected grids on the openlayer ( Grids are configured in Geoserver).

How can i achieve this using Restful API. Kindly advise.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please create a new post for your question !