# Openlayers-5 WFS-T: formatGML with srsName:'EPSG:4326'

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I'm implementing a editing feature with WFS-T and I realise that when I use srsName: 'EPSG:3857' in my formatGML every thing run good, but whe I use a different one e.g. srsName:'EPSG:EPSG:4326' I get a projction erro from the Geoserver.

My layer has the `EPSG:4326` projection set.

Anyone has any adeia what is wrong?

```
var formatWFS = new WFS();
var formatGML = new GML({
  featureNS: 'cesan',
  featureType: 'Escola',
  srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
  version: '1.1.0'
});

var transactWFS = function (action, feature) {

  if(feature == null)
    return;

  let node;
  switch (action) {

    case 'insert':
      feature.set('nome', 'Insert Test test test');
      node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([feature], null, null, formatGML);
      break;

    case 'update':
      feature.set('nome', 'Update Update Update Update');
      node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [feature], null, formatGML);
      break;

    case 'delete':      
      node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, null, [feature], formatGML);
      break;
  }

  $.ajax({
    service: 'WFS',
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cesan/wfs",
    dataType: 'xml',
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'text/xml',
    data: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node),

    contentType: 'text/xml',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(formatWFS.readTransactionResponse(data));
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    },
    context: this
  }).done(function() {
    vectorSource.clear();
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    map.removeInteraction(select);
    select.getFeatures().clear();
  });
};
```

The error mensage:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for Point: org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.PointOutsideEnvelopeException: -2308718.3342682673 outside of (-180.0,180.0)
```

Thanks a lot,
Warley Mendes

Comment: The standard definition of EPSG:4326 is LatLon but OpenLayers uses its own LonLat definition.  When interfacing with other systems the array needs to be reversed or you can use CRS:84 which is LonLat in all systems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648061/error-when-posting-features-to-postgis-by-openlayers-and-geoserver

Comment: Also the 4th parameter of `writeTransaction` should be an options object (as on your `formatGML`) not the actual format unless passed as `{gmlOptions: formatGML}`